# Parameterizing an incomplete case statement in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I am trying to parameterize some code I have written. The non parameterized version below is written for WIDTH = 4. I have a reg `digits` that cycles a zero. Based on where this zero is I want to output a particular vector to `segments` from my array `SS` (I assign values to it elsewhere).

```
reg [6:0] SS [3:0];    

always @(posedge clk)
    if (reset) digits <= 4'b1110;
    else       digits <= { digits[2:0], digits[3] };

always @(*)
    if (reset) segments <= ~7'h0;
    else case(~digits)
        4'b1    : segments[6:0] <= ~SS[0];
        4'b10   : segments[6:0] <= ~SS[1];
        4'b100  : segments[6:0] <= ~SS[2];
        4'b1000 : segments[6:0] <= ~SS[3];
        default : segments[6:0] <=  7'h0;
    endcase
```

How can I parameterize this case statement for a different width of `digits`? I've tried using a `for` loop instead of a case statement like this:

```
for (genvar i = 0; i < WIDTH; i = i+1) begin
    if (~digits[i]) segments[6:0] <= ~SS[i];
end
```

But it won't synthesize because it says `segments` has multiple drivers and if I do it in a different way like below it says `digits` is not constant so it can't synthesize:

```
for (genvar i = 0; i < WIDTH; i = i+1) begin
    if (~digits == (1 << i)) segments[6:0] <= ~SS[i];
end
```

How can I do this? I have thought of taking the log base 2 of `~digits` and checking if that is equal to `i` within the loop but I'm not sure how to do that in hardware. Is there a better way?

Comment: what is declaration of `SS` ? can you upload full code?

Comment: @PrakashDarji I updated it

Comment: also tell declaration of segment?

Comment: where is your `generate` and `engenerate`? In generate, either `awalys` block or `assign` statment is use to assign value to `segments`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a loop and take advantage of the "last assignment wins". See below. I used some SystemVerilog syntax here, but you could do it without it.

```
PARAMETER SS_SIZE = 4
logic [6:0] SS [SS_SIZE];
logic [SS_SIZE-1:0] digits;

always_ff @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
    if (reset) digits <= {{(SS_SIZE-1){1'b1}},1'b0};
    else       digits <= { digits[SS_SIZEE-2:0], digits[SS_SIZE-1] };

always_comb begin
    segments = '0;
    for(int i=0; i<SS_SIZE; i++) begin
       if(digits[i]==1'b0) begin
          segments = ~SS[i];
       end
    end
 end
```

I would go further and replace the shift register with a binary counter:

```
PARAMETER SS_SIZE = 4
logic [6:0] SS [SS_SIZE];
logic [$clog2(SS_SIZE)-1:0] count;

always_ff @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
    if (reset) count <= '0;
    else if(count == (SS_SIZE-1)) count <= '0
    else       count <= count+1;

assign segments = ~SS[count];
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! I was previously putting the `for` loop between a `generate` and `endgenerate`. Do you think you could clarify what would be different in hardware between putting it there and not? And can you explain "last assignment wins"?

Comment: You are allowed to drive something multiple times in the loop as long as the last assignment is the one you want to stick. The synthesis tools are smart enough to figure out minimal hardware for this. There probably isn't any difference between my answer and one that uses a generate block.